# Como alterar o gênero da voz do sintetizador Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis?

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um programa de reconhecimento e sintetização de voz usando *microsoft speech* e *system.speech*, porém a voz feminina é utilizada por padrão.É possível alterar para a voz masculina? utilizei o comando `sp.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);` porém não altera.

Comment: Microsoft Speech só funciona bem com a língua inglesa. Melhor é criar uma aplicação Universal Windows app e ou usar a [Cortana](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands) ou então a API de [reconhecimento de fala](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition)

Comment: A ideia é que a aplicação seja utilizada por pessoas que não falam inglês, mas obrigado!!

Comment: Jovem, não mude o foco da sua pergunta **nunca**, sobretudo se já há uma resposta (como é o caso aqui). Se você tem uma nova dúvida abra uma nova pergunta, é de graça.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se tem a ver, mas creio que talvez setar a idade:

```
sp.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Adult);
```

- `VoiceAge.Child` indica para usar a voz de uma criança de 10 anos.
- `VoiceAge.Teen`   indica para usar a voz de um adolescente de 15 anos.
- `VoiceAge.Adult` indica para usar a voz de um adulto de 30 anos.
- `VoiceAge.Senior` indica para usar a voz de um senhor de 65 anos.

Como é descrito em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/dd146920%28v%3doffice.14%29

Pode ser o que o Augusto disse também, em português o suporte não é muito bom.

Comment: @LINQ eu e minhas gafes de português :) Grato pela edição

Comment: Super normal, erros acontecem hehe. Eu aproveitei para ver se a edição também ficava nesse estilo retrô (que eu estou adorando, btw) hahaha.